# Using a variable as a Save file name ~ im.save(type, '.png')

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, formatting, syntax-error

This is what I'm inputting:

```
type = 'filename'
im.save(type, '.png')
```

and what this is supposed to do is save the file in a .png format but with the variable as the name, I'm just not 100% sure how the format/syntax is supposed to be laid out.

Is it the same as if I wanted to print the variable:

```
Print(type, "This shows up beside the type I think")
```

edit, Don't pay to much attention to the list, it's mostly there as an example. I not sure how to have a variable right beside a Plain text word like this im.save(type, 'PLAINTEXT')

Comment: Do you want to do it for each element in the list `type`?

Comment: The list isan't really that important, i'm just not sure how i would go about doing this 'im.save(type, '.png')' but in the correct format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to use PIL, please, use it like this:

```
file_name = 'my_file'
im.save( file_name + '.png' )
```

will result in `my_file.png` saved to your disk.

Comment: K this is the answer, Thank's alot for the help !  btw ty for the simple answer it was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is string formatting:

```
type = 'filename'
im.save("{0}.png".format(type))
```

This will create `filename.png`.

Also `'Print' != 'print'`.