# Python - PIL Save & Rename Image From HTML file Using alt Description

Tags: python, image, save, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save images from html files based on this thread
[How do I extract images from html files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610728/how-do-i-extract-images-from-html-files-in-a-directory)

```
import os, os.path
from PIL import Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

path = 'c:/Users/Desktop/html/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
for f in files:
    soup = bs(open(os.path.join(root, f)), 'lxml')

    for image in soup.find_all("img"):
        image = image.get('src')
        alt = image.get('alt')

        im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, image))   

        im.save(path+image+alt, "png")

        print(os.path.join(root, image))







Content of the html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Image1Name">
</body>
</html>
```

Complete file path for the image is

c:/Users/Desktop/html/images/1.jpg
**After**
c:/Users/Desktop/html/images/Image1Name.png

I have looked at these threads :
[Using a variable as a Save file name ~ im.save(type, '.png')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765021/using-a-variable-as-a-save-file-name-im-savetype-png)
[Modify path name when saving with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646343/modify-path-name-when-saving-with-pil)

error

soup = bs(open(os.path.join(root, f)), 'lxml')
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py", line 191, in **init**
    markup = markup.read()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 77: character maps to

How can I save and rename the image from the html file using the alt description correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't experience your encoding problem, so I can't help there.

To help a bit though, I would change im.save(path+image+alt, "png") to im.save(os.path.join(path, os.path.dirname(image), alt+'.png'))

- Replacing the + signs with os.path.join is just to improve general
  handling
- Replacing image with os.path.dirname(image) is because you
  don't want 'images/1.jpg', you want 'images'
- Adding '.png' to alt is
  because you probably want to name the file 'Image1Name.png' rather
  than 'Image1Name'. After that, the second argument of "png" is not
  needed.

Also, your code -

```
for image in soup.find_all("img"):
    image = image.get('src')
    alt = image.get('alt')
```

has a problem. "image = image.get('src')" changes "image" to be a string, meaning that "image.get('alt')" will then have an error. I would recommend instead -

```
for img in soup.find_all("img"):
    image = img.get('src')
    alt = img.get('alt')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions  -  although I still get the error message, I dont mind. It renames the images  - thank you again! :)